# How to display the first 3 elements in UL only on document load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a List (UL) which has a class of .more_stories the UL contains LI.

I use this code to hide them by default on load:

```
$('ul.more_stories li').css({'display': 'none'});
```

Now I want to display the first 3 li items inside the UL after that. How can I do that in jQuery?

-Note: I have several ULs with the same class.

I try that and I get unexpected results..

```
// more stories
$('ul.more_stories li').css({'display': 'none'});
$('ul.more_stories li:gt(2)').show();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want the [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector instead, like this:

```
$('ul.more_stories li').hide();
$('ul.more_stories li:lt(3)').show();
```

Or, a bit simpler/faster using [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$('ul.more_stories li').hide().slice(0, 2).show();
```

This approach hides them all, then using the same set and taking the 0-2 index elements to show.

---

You can also reverse the approach, never hiding the first 3, like this:

```
$('ul.more_stories li:gt(2)').hide();
```

Or, again using [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$('ul.more_stories li').slice(3).hide();
```

---

For comments, to make this work across multiple `<ul>` element, use a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop, like this:

```
$('ul.more_stories').each(function() {
  $(this).children().slice(3).hide(); 
});
```

Comment: Great. that works for the first UL only. if I have several ULs with the same class .more_stories.. how can I apply it to all ULs ? thank you again

Comment: @Ahmad - I'd use a `.each()` in that case (since `:nth-child()` would be messy/repetitive), for example: `$('ul.more_stories').each(function() { $(this).children().slice(3).hide(); });`

Comment: Thank you, managed to sort it out $('ul.more_stories li').css({'display': 'none'});
$("ul.more_stories").each(function(){
$(this).children('li').slice(0, 2).show();
}); is that correct?

Comment: @Ahmad - yup, though there's no reason to hide them show them...just hide *only* the ones you don't want in one pass, I added how to do this above :)